# Python unable to access all the elements of lists list IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, list

I have a variable with lists

```
list1 = [{u'key': 1, u'doc_count': 17804}]
[{u'key': u'01', u'doc_count': 516}, {u'key': u'10', u'doc_count': 368},  {u'key': u'50', u'doc_count': 156}, {u'key': u'02', u'doc_count': 116}]
[{u'key': u'40', u'doc_count': 1144},{u'key': u'4P', u'doc_count': 127}]
[u'key': 0, u'doc_count': 16342}, {u'key': 1, u'doc_count': 1462}]
```

I want to access all the elements of this like:

```
{u'key': 1, u'doc_count': 17804}
{u'key': u'01', u'doc_count': 516}
{u'key': u'10', u'doc_count': 368}
{u'key': u'50', u'doc_count': 156}
{u'key': u'02', u'doc_count': 116}
{u'key': u'40', u'doc_count': 1144}
{u'key': u'4P', u'doc_count': 127}
{u'key': 0, u'doc_count': 16342}
{u'key': 1, u'doc_count': 1462}
```

but I'm only able to access the first element of every list like with

```
list1[0] = 
{u'key': 1, u'doc_count': 17804}
{u'key': u'01', u'doc_count': 516}
{u'key': u'40', u'doc_count': 1144}
{u'key': 0, u'doc_count': 16342}
```

I'm unable to access the second, third, etc elements of these lists.
I tried list[1] but I'm getting an Index error.

Comment: Your data sample doesn't seem to match your output example for `list1[0]`. I think you're missing some comma's and brackets in your sample.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have defined your list of lists wrongly and that's why you are getting the error. Apart from that you were missing a dict opening braces which i assume is a typo.

```
list1 = [{u'key': 1, u'doc_count': 17804}]
#####################THIS LIST ENDS HERE ^
#all below lines are not considered
[{u'key': u'01', u'doc_count': 516}, {u'key': u'10', u'doc_count': 368},  {u'key': u'50', u'doc_count': 156}, {u'key': u'02', u'doc_count': 116}]
[{u'key': u'40', u'doc_count': 1144},{u'key': u'4P', u'doc_count': 127}]
[{u'key': 0, u'doc_count': 16342}, {u'key': 1, u'doc_count': 1462}]

#You only have one item in list1 so you will get an error

#lets now make it a proper list of lists
list1 = [ #<see this open brackets?
[{u'key': 1, u'doc_count': 17804}],
[{u'key': u'01', u'doc_count': 516}, {u'key': u'10', u'doc_count': 368},  {u'key': u'50', u'doc_count': 156}, {u'key': u'02', u'doc_count': 116}],
[{u'key': u'40', u'doc_count': 1144},{u'key': u'4P', u'doc_count': 127}],
[{u'key': 0, u'doc_count': 16342}, {u'key': 1, u'doc_count': 1462}]
] #it ends here

#python 2.7x
for sublist in list1:
    for d in sublist:
        print(d)

#print all of the dicts - python 3.x
#[print(dict) for sublist in list1 for dict in sublist]
```

Output

```
{'key': 1, 'doc_count': 17804}
{'key': '01', 'doc_count': 516}
{'key': '10', 'doc_count': 368}
{'key': '50', 'doc_count': 156}
{'key': '02', 'doc_count': 116}
{'key': '40', 'doc_count': 1144}
{'key': '4P', 'doc_count': 127}
{'key': 0, 'doc_count': 16342}
{'key': 1, 'doc_count': 1462}
```

Comment: But `list1[0]` would not give the output the OP showed in the question. It also wouldn't be valid JSON, which the question is tagged with. I've decided to delete my answer because the OP didn't actually give a reproducible example so it just seems a bit pointless to do the fixing for them.

Comment: @roganjosh I think OP has mentioned "I'm only able to access the first element of every list like with". I think he meant the first dict.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you have 4 *independent lists* (of dictionaries), the first with the name `list1`, and the others without names.

The `list1` list has *only 1 element* (a dictionary), so the only valid index for it is `0` - `list1[0]` is valid, but `list[1]` is not, as such element *doesn't exist*.

You probably wanted concatenate all those lists, so the quick fix is to *append the first 3 lines with*
`+ \`:

```
list1 = [{u'key': 1, u'doc_count': 17804}] + \
    [{u'key': u'01', u'doc_count': 516}, {u'key': u'10', u'doc_count': 368},  {u'key': u'50', u'doc_count': 156}, {u'key': u'02', u'doc_count': 116}] + \
    [{u'key': u'40', u'doc_count': 1144},{u'key': u'4P', u'doc_count': 127}] + \
    [u'key': 0, u'doc_count': 16342}, {u'key': 1, u'doc_count': 1462}]
```

(I indented the last 3 lines for readibility, too), but [PEP8 - Style guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#should-a-line-break-before-or-after-a-binary-operator) prefers write the same as

```
list1 = ([{u'key': 1, u'doc_count': 17804}]
    + [{u'key': u'01', u'doc_count': 516}, {u'key': u'10', u'doc_count': 368},  {u'key': u'50', u'doc_count': 156}, {u'key': u'02', u'doc_count': 116}]
    + [{u'key': u'40', u'doc_count': 1144},{u'key': u'4P', u'doc_count': 127}]
    + [u'key': 0, u'doc_count': 16342}, {u'key': 1, u'doc_count': 1462}])
```

(in parentheses to avoid the need of the line continuation symbols `\`, and with *prefixed* operator `+`.)

Other option is to *remove all square brackets except the first one and the last one* and *put commas at the end of the first 3 lines:*

```
list1 = [{u'key': 1, u'doc_count': 17804},
    {u'key': u'01', u'doc_count': 516}, {u'key': u'10', u'doc_count': 368},  {u'key': u'50', u'doc_count': 156}, {u'key': u'02', u'doc_count': 116},
    {u'key': u'40', u'doc_count': 1144},{u'key': u'4P', u'doc_count': 127},
    u'key': 0, u'doc_count': 16342}, {u'key': 1, u'doc_count': 1]
```

In this case the line continuation symbol `\` is not needed, too.